# UIStackView children equally spaced (around and between)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uistackview

How can I have an UIStackView with the **same space as padding and gap** between views?

How can I achieve this layout:

[image: Expected layout]

When this one doesn't suit me:

[image: No good layout]

Neither does this:

[image]

I just need the around views space to be the same as the between views space.
Why is it so hard?

**Important**
I'm using [my fork](https://github.com/gfpacheco/TZStackView) of [TZStackView](https://github.com/tomvanzummeren/TZStackView) to support iOS 7. So no `layoutMargins` for me :(

Comment: Are you working with a storyboard or programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who keep getting here looking for a solution for this problem. I found that the best way (in my case) would be to use a parent `UIView` as background and padding, like this:

[image]

In this case the `UIStackView` is contrained to the edges of the `UIView` with a padding and separate the subviews with spacing.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an older question, but the way I solved it was to add two UIViews with zero size at the beginning and end of my stack, then use the `.equalSpacing` distribution.

*Note: this only guarantees equal around spacing along the main axis of the stack view (i.e. the left and right edges in my example)*

```
let stack = UIStackView()

stack.axis         = .horizontal
stack.alignment    = .center
stack.distribution = .equalSpacing

// add content normally
// ...

// add extra views for spacing
stack.insertArrangedSubview(UIView(), at: 0)
stack.addArrangedSubview(UIView())
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can almost achieve what you want using a UIStackView. When you set some constraints yourself on the UIViews inside the UIStackView you can come up with this:

[image]

This is missing the left and right padding that you are looking for. The problem is that `UIStackView` is adding its own constraints when you add views to it. In this case you can add `top` and `bottom` constraints to get the vertical padding, but when you try to add a `trailing` constraint for the right padding, `UIStackView` ignores or overrides that constraint. Interestingly adding a `leading` constraint for the left padding works.

But setting constraints on `UIStackView's` arranged subviews is not what you want to do anyway. The whole point of using a `UIStackView` is to just give it some views and let `UIStackView` handle the rest.

To achieve what you are trying to do is actually not too hard. Here is an example of a `UIViewController` that contains a custom stack view that can handle padding on all sides (I used [SnapKit](http://snapkit.io/) for the constraints):

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let padding: CGFloat = 30

        let customStackView = UIView()
        customStackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.1)
        view.addSubview(customStackView)
        customStackView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.left.equalTo(padding)
            make.right.equalTo(-padding)
        }

        // define an array of subviews
        let views = [UIView(), UIView(), UIView()]

        // UIView does not have an intrinsic contentSize
        // so you have to set some heights
        // In a real implementation the height will be determined
        // by the views' content, but for this example
        // you have to set the height programmatically
        views[0].snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.height.equalTo(150)
        }
        views[1].snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.height.equalTo(120)
        }
        views[2].snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.height.equalTo(130)
        }

        // Iterate through the views and set the constraints
        var leftHandView: UIView? = nil
        for view in views {
            customStackView.addSubview(view)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.15)

            view.snp_makeConstraints(closure: { (make) -> Void in
                make.top.equalTo(padding)
                make.bottom.lessThanOrEqualTo(-padding)
                if let leftHandView = leftHandView {
                    make.left.equalTo(leftHandView.snp_right).offset(padding)
                    make.width.equalTo(leftHandView)
                } else {
                    make.left.equalTo(padding)
                }
                leftHandView = view
            })
        }

        if let lastView = views.last {
            lastView.snp_makeConstraints(closure: { (make) -> Void in
                make.right.equalTo(-padding)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following results:

[image]

Comment: That's some really good answer you have, I really appreciate it! But as you said, it misses the point of having the UIStackView to take care of the constraints =/

Comment: That's true, but the thing you are trying to achieve is just not possible with a `UIStackView`. There is just no thing like padding, just spacing, but that's only affecting the space inbetween views, not around them